# Multiple conditions in objective C

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a small problem with the objective c and conditions. How can we show that on 6 conditions that I give at least 3 must be verified as correct?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
if (condition1) counter++;
if (condition2) counter++;
if (condition3) counter++;
if (condition4) counter++;
if (condition5) counter++;
if (condition6) counter++;
if (counter >= 3) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for for quick and perfect help

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as :

```
int validated=0;

if(condition1){
    validated++;
}
if(condition2){
    validated++;
}
if(condition3){
    validated++;
}
if(condition4){
    validated++;
}
if(condition5){
    validated++;
}
if(condition6){
    validated++;
}
if(validated>=3){
      //do your stuffs
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try counting the correct conditions:

pseudo-code:

```
int counter = 0;
if(A) counter++;
if(B) counter++;
if(C) counter++;
if(D) counter++;
if(E) counter++;
if(F) counter++;

if(counter >= 3){
//do stuff here
}
counter = 0;
```

Comment: could be if (!(A==true)==0)

Comment: Thank you very much for for quick and perfect help

Comment: sorry - too much php lately

Comment: In obj-c idiom, drop the `== true`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, here is a more flexible solution for a variable number of conditions:

```
int conditions[6] = {condition1, condition2, condition3, 
                     condition4, condition5, condition6};
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(conditions)/sizeof(int); i++) {
    counter += conditions[i];  // Assuming your conditions are 0 or 1.
}
if (counter >= 3) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You can optimize this code, inside for loop, `if(counter==3) break;` :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 @interface Conditions
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *conditions;

 - (void) addCondition: (Condition*) theCondition;
 - (NSInteger) count;
 - (NSInteger) satisfying: ( void (^block)(Condition*)  );
 @end
```

Wrap your list of conditions in an object.  When you need to know if three conditions are satisfied:

```
 if ([self.conditions satisfying: ^(Condition *c){ return [c isSatisfied]; })>3) {...};
```

This is overkill -- perhaps ludicrous overkill -- if this is a disposable project.  But if long-term maintenance is an issue, this decouples the condition from details of implementation. You avoid the long list of conditionals. You can add or change conditions easily, and if their logical gets complicated, you have a nice object-oriented interface for coping with it. (Condition is probably an protocol operating as a Facade, not an object).